# Java, return a linkedlist from a linkedlist parameter

Tags: java, list, methods, collections, parameters

I am trying to create a method which returns the place values of any two digits in a list that sum to zero. Where I am getting stuck is: creating the return method type, choosing the appropriate parameter to pass, and creating an empty list which holds the values to return.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
public class TwoSums {

public LinkedList<Integer> sum_values(LinkedList<Integer> input){
```

(Above) I am trying (but not sure how) to return a linked list from the     method. I want the parameter to be a list with values like {3,-3,0,1}. I am also unsure of what the return type should be here.

```
    int iterator = 0;
    int scanner = 0;
    LinkedList positions = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

(Above)  I am trying to create an empty list which I can push the place values of the parameter into, if they sum to zero

```
    while(iterator<input.length){ 
        if (iterator + scanner !=0){
            scanner ++;}
        else if (iterator + scanner ==0){
            //push iterator and scanner values to the linkedlist
```

Comment: Hint: read about java naming conventions. The only place for the _ char is in SOME_CONSTANT; you dont use it for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably your homework, so I will just give you some guiding thoughts; I wont do the work for you!

First of all, the return type. Thing is: you can't just return *single* numbers. Because, you are interested in **pairs** of numbers. Thus you need some class like

```
public class IndexPair {
  private final int firstIndex;
  private final int secondIndex;

  public IndexPair(int first, int second) { this.firstIndex = first ...
```

and then your method can simply return a `List<IndexPair>` object. Note: if you are serious here, you would want to override the **equals** method for example; in order to allow for easy comparison of IndexPair objects.

And of course: Java already knows some Pair classes which could be used here; instead of inventing your own thing.

The other problem: finding those pairs. A naive solution would be:

```
List<IndexPair> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (int firstIndex = 0; firstIndex < input.size(); firstIndex++) {
  for (int secondIndex = firstIndex+1; secondIndex < input.size(); secondIndex++) {
    if (input.get(firstIndex) + input.get(secondIndex) == 0) {
       results.add(new IndexPair(firstIndex, secondIndex));
```

As said; the above is meant to get you going. There might be some typos or subtle bugs in that code. Take it as inspiration and work with it until it does what you need!

Edit: calling your method is as as

```
List<IndexPair> pairs = sum_values(Arrays.asList(-3, 3, 0, 0))
```

for example. But please understand: that is really basic stuff. Just do some reading around Lists and arrays. Those things have been documented many many times.

Comment: hi @GhostCat what I am still confused about is how to pass the values {3, -3, 0,1} in the parameter. Would we need n static variables for n values passed to the parameter? Ex) {3, -3, 0,1} would have values firstIndex...fourthIndex.  Then it seems we are looping to compare the static values, and if two sum to zero, return that pair?  Sorry, I am just a huge newb here trying to wrap my head around this.